# Tab fails to go into selected state until clicked twice (the first time)

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

This has been happening for a long time since I have been working with jQuery UI Tabs, as seen on http://eq4.net/hive/ - upon first loading the page (or after adding a tab for that matter).

After clicking once, the load and show events get triggered, but no content loads into the panel, and the currently selected tab index is set to -1 (none) and the tabs all fall out of selected state.

Then if you click again, everything operates as you would expect, until you add a tab.

Can someone point me in the right direction so I can begin to debug this quirk? There is nothing in my code which should have any effect on tab selection, most of it is updating other aspects of the UI which seems to happen correctly.

I am using jQuery UI 1.8.20 and jQuery 1.7.2 - thank you

Answer (score 0):

try putting this

```
      $( "#pages" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({ 
              axis: "x",   sort: function(event, ui) {
                        },
```

in Document.Ready

```
      $(document).ready(function () {
            $( "#pages" ).tabs().find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
                axis: "x",
                sort: function(event, ui) {

            },
      });
```

Comment: I am not sure if this pertains to selection at all, I don't want sortable quite yet. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Confirm the behaviour you report and can only suggest a workaround by which, after a tab is added, the previously selected tab is automatically re-selected *twice*. The first select will be the buggy ineffective one and the second will actually reselect the tab (and its associated panel).

Something along the following lines maybe :

```
$(function(){

    ...

    var selectedTab = null;

    $(selector).tabs({
          ...
          select: function(event, ui) {
              //Keep `selectedTab` up to date to remember the selected tab
              selectedTab = ui.tab; //or ui.index?
          }
          add: function(event, ui) {
               //Here re-select selectedTab twice (if not null).
               //Probably easier to use selectedTab.trigger('click') than the tabs' .select() method, (which requires the selector to be known).
          }
    });
});
```

It's difficult to see how to handle the special case where no tab has yet been selected (ie. `selectedTab === null`).

This would be a nasty, inefficient fudge (and not recommended with ajax mode) but would save having to hack the plugin (which, if easily fixable, would have been fixed).

Comment: I am already tracking the select event and which tab/prev tab has been clicked for other things so it shouldn't be too much trouble for me to  force it to behave. I was just hoping it was something simple I overlooked or lack experience with. I will keep researching and see if I can't fix the plugin if that's what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was the fx option causing this behavior, I will venture to guess the event bubbler didn't bubble right.

upon removing:

```
fx: {
     opacity: 'toggle',
    duration: 100
}
```

tabs now load as they should. I will explore exactly what does (and doesn't) happen when using the fx option and report back.

Comment: Someone else has come up with the [same conclusions as yourself](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jqueryui-tabs-add-ajax-tab-programatically-get-blank-display-upon-initial-click).

Answer (score 0):

With credit to Google, it is apparent that there are several issues to do with jQuery UI tabs' `.add()` method, however the following process seems (unsurprisingly?) to be thoroughly reliable:

- call `.tabs('destroy')`
- append a new tab (ie. a new `li` node), "manually"
- re-initialize `.tabs()`

On the surface, this is quite simple to achieve though in practice there are a few hoops to jump through in the development of generalized working code - chiefly:

- the need to preserve the native `.add()` method's ability to insert tabs at any index, not just at the end
- the need to maintain track of the currently selected tab and to re-select it after re-initialization
- the need to ensure that the full range of UI's `.tabs()` options remains available.

Great, a chance to write something challenging!

After playing with the code for a while, I came to the conclusion that a "feeder" (more conventionally an "adapter") pattern was more appropriate (and simpler) than a patch or monkey-patch for the UI tabs plugin itself and after several iterations I came up with a lightweight jQuery plugin to do the job :

```
$.fn['tabsFeeder'] = function(options) {
    this.on('addTab', function(event, url, label, index) {
        var $that = $(this),
            s = $that.data('tabs').options;
        $that.tabs('destroy');
        try {
            var $lis = $that.find('li'),
                n = $lis.length;
            index = Math.max((index === undefined) ? n : index, 0);
            $lis.eq(Math.min(index, n - 1))[(index < n) ? 'before' : 'after']('<li><a href="' + url + '">' + label + '</a></li>');
            if (s.selected !== undefined && index <= s.selected) {
                s.selected += 1;
            }
            throw ('');
        }
        catch (e) {
            $that.tabs(s);
        }
    });

    this.on('current', function(event, callback) {
        $that = $(this);
        if ($that.eq(0).length > 0 && typeof callback === 'function') {
            var ui = {
                'tab': $that.find('li.ui-state-active a'),
                'panel': $that.find('.ui-tabs-panel').not('.ui-tabs-hide'),
                'index': $that.tabs('option', 'selected')
            };
            callback(event, ui);
        }
    });
    this.tabs(options);
};
```

Trust me, it's lightweight.

With this plugin (and jQuery UI tabs) in place, the bottom line is that we can now:

- initialize tabs with `$('selector').tabsFeeder(options)`, where `options` are the standard jQuery UI tabs options - no additions and no omissions
- call `$('selector').trigger("addTab", [url, label]);` or `$('selector').trigger("addTab", [url, label, index]);` instead of `.tabs("add", url, label)` or `.tabs("add", url, label, index)`.

And for good measure, I included a `current` custom event to give access to the currently selected tab (delivered to a callback function as a "ui" object as per tabs native events).

I'm not sure I can thoroughly justify the use of a custom event handlers instead of proper method, except to say that the plugin :

- was easier to write
- is more concise
- doesn't need to write any data of its own to the DOM.
- method chaining is guaranteed

You can see `tabsFeeder` in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zBVah/13/)

**Shortcomings**

Because `tabsFeeder` relies on reinitializing `.tabs()`, it is inefficient and probably unsuitable for use with ajax mode as content may need to be re-fetched - but by all means try - performance may be acceptable.

The "addTab" event handler uses UI tabs plugin's `select` event to track the current tab. In order to allow a `select` callback to be specified in the options, I opted for a compact observer-like pattern in which the firing order is hard-coded as standard callback (if present) followed by the plugin's `defaultSelect()` (one JavaScript statement). Whereas this seems logical and works fine in the demo, it is not fully explored and I can't guarantee that it will be correct in all applications. It would be possible to allow the order (A-B versus B-A) to be established programmatically, but this would be tedious to code and probably not necessary.